# как получить url в bs4?

Tags: python-3.x, bs4

Имеется вот такая ссылка https://i.imgur.com/VB94oZV.png после перехода она станет https://i.imgur.com/removed.png нужно как-то получить url страницы

Comment: не все ссылки переходят в https://i.imgur.com/removed.png и мне нужно это отслеживать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если селениум то можно

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print (driver.current_url)
```

или

```
import requests


link = "https://stackoverflow.com"
data = requests.request("GET", link)
url = data.url
```

Comment: нежелательно,  прога вся написанна на bs4 зачем ещё и селен подключать, второе точно то что надо